# Reusing constants and properties in a maven project?

Tags: java, database, maven, jpa, pom.xml

I have a few plugins in **pom.xml** that need database connection properties. Such us: driver, url, user name, password. All these preferences I already have in **persistence.xml** file. Can I use them directly, without creating new files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

even if you could, it wont be pretty. you could do it the other way around - specify those parameters as properties in the pom.xml (or a properties file alongside it) and use [maven resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to inject them into persistence.xml and any other file that requires them @built time.

so you'd have, in your pom.xml, something like:

```
<properties>
   <db.driver.class>com.acme.db.JdbcDriver</db.driver.class>
   <db.url>localhost</db.url>
</properties>
...
<build>
   <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
   </resources>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         ...
         <configuration>
            <connection>${db.driver.class}/${db.url}</connection>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

and in your persistence.xml you could use ${db.driver.class} and have it replaced by maven during the build.

Comment: I am in situation, that I have several profiles to connect to db. They stored in persistence.xml and in some json file. And I don't see reasons to organize them in pom.xml.

Comment: I need some way to use this profiles properties in maven from persistence or json file directly (something like in properties maven plugin)

Comment: im unaware of any existing way to do this. its possible to write a maven plugin that will run early enough in the build lifecycle (maybe the validate phase), locate those files and populate project properties based on values in those files. for an example of a simple maven plugin that populates project properties i'd look into this one - https://code.google.com/p/maven-svn-revision-number-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for help. In my situation I forced to use properties file.